# Error en categorias prestashop

Tags: prestashop

por si alguien pudiera ayudarme con este problema que tengo en mi página web, en la categoría de calzado tengo un problema con una marca en concreto y es que se me ve tal que así, adjunto captura de pantalla, he estado toqueteando pero no doy con el fallo para arreglarlo.
Muchas gracias de antemano.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Considera leer [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, además realiza el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) ¡Y obtendrás tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/what-are-badges)! Observaciones: a tu pregunta le falta código, si no lo tienes puede que este no sea el sitio para esta clase de preguntas

Answer (score 0):

lo haz hecho uno a uno o haz utilizado el importador de data de prestashop? ya que con el importar articulos tienes que definir si incluye en inicio o no... tu error sucede cuando se define mas de una categoria, sub categoria. sub sub categoria.. etc puedes ser infinitos niveles de categorias